# Puppet server on an puppet agent CRL error

Tags: puppet

After installing puppet server on a puppet agent, I keep getting this error on the next puppet run.

```
Error: The CRL issued by 'CN=Puppet CA: puppet.aws.domain.com' is missing
Error: The CRL issued by 'CN=Puppet CA: puppet.aws.domain.com' is missing
```

It seems to be that the puppet server removes the issued CRL from the main puppet server. Regenerating another certificate does work however if the new puppet server ever restarts it will delete the issued CRL again.

My question now is: Is it possible to keep the issued CRL when I make a puppet agent to a puppet server?

Comment: This question would be better suited for [Server Fault SE](https://serverfault.com/).